# gstreamer audio/video pipeline for screencast recording

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, gnome, screen-recording

I am trying to record audio/video screencasts using gstreamer pipeline, by
modifying the standard gnome gstreamer pipeline to include pulsesrc audio.

With

```
pactl list | grep -A2 'Source #' | grep 'Name: .*\.monitor$' | cut -d" " -f2
```

I query all available audio monitor sources, in my case:

```
alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
```

my complete gstreamer pipeline:

```
queue ! videorate ! \
vp8enc min_quantizer=13 max_quantizer=13 cpu-used=5 deadline=1000000 threads=%T ! \
queue ! muxout. \
pulsesrc device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! \
audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! queue ! muxout. \
webmmux name=muxout
```

this gives me synchronized audio/video output, however I see problems:

- heavy frame drops due to high cpu load (without audio included it is fine)
- the resulting webm file seems broken in terms of keyframes or something..

Any advices appreciated ;)